# Which web or browser technology is the best solution for my requirement?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement to build a website where the user can choose a design from a standard template and a number of optional parts. So for example, it could be selecting an outfit, where there is a fixed template image of a person, and the user selects different colour trousers, shirts, socks etc from a scrolling list of images. When the user selects a particular item from the list, the image appears on the template giving an indication of the overall look.

It doesn't have to be too fancy with any moving images or transitions, but just the ability to overlay fixed images onto the template.

What would be my best choice of technology and way of going about it? Standard HTML? Css? Javascript? Something more server orientated such as JSP? Would appreciate any input.

Comment: Yes, you’re going to be hard-pressed not to use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it in many ways, it mostly depends on your requirements and what you're comfortable with doing.

Personally I would have done it with plain javascript based on the description you gave.

Requirements:

- Change images during runtime.

  > JavaScript does a good job with this.
- Predefined coordinates for where the overlay needs to be positioned.

  > Some type of storage for the coordinates, simplest possible would be hardcoded values in your script.
- Ability to position the image as an overlay at said coordinates.

  > CSS with `position: absolute;` can be used for this.
- Image stacking and index logic.

  > Can be done with JavaScript.

This is the simplest solution to the problem given. If you have more complex needs like zooming or resizing, you may want to check out `<canvas>`.